# Solution for Dynamic Schemas - HIVE/AVRO

Tags: hadoop, hive, schema

The requirement is to keep up with the schema evolution for target ORC table. I am receiving JSON events from source. We plan to convert these to AVRO (since it supports schema evolution). Since schema can change daily/weekly, we need to keep ingesting new data JSON files, convert them to AVRO and store all the data (old/new) in an ORC hive table. How do we solve for this?

Comment: Is the source able to just send Avro? If not, can you ingest events into NiFi or Kafka, for example, then generate Avro from that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below approach, which is one among many different ways that you can implement to solve this.

**1. Create HBASE Table**

- Read the AVRO data and create table in HBASE initially.( You can use spark to do this efficiently)
- HBASE table will take care of schema evolution even in the future.

**2. Create Hive Wrapper Table**

- Create a hive wrapper table (storage handlers) pointing to the HBASE table. (You can read more about it [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StorageHandlers)

**3. Create ORC Table**

- Now create ORC table from the table created in step2

**4. Things you need to handle**

- Since Hive tables are tightly coupled with a schema, you need to handle a step before writing the data into Hive wrapper table in step 2. You need to identify the new columns here and then add the columns appropriately to the existing wrapper or ORC table. This again can be achieved by NiFi or Spark or as simple as a shell script. Choose the right tools according to your use case.

Comment: Hive can handle evolution fine... http://getindata.com/schema-evolution-with-avro-and-hive/ What is the purpose of the extra legwork to include HBase?

Comment: In Ideal case you might not need HBase, but if you just maintain your data in Hive and if your source is changing the datatypes or column names or any such changes, it is easy to handle if your data is in HBase. For more practical purposes, It is a good idea to put up your data in HBase.